# How to find the C# component that contains a particular class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, components

I'm creating an Internet Explorer plugin using C#. I've been following a tutorial where the code imports a couple of classes that I don't have available, namely:

```
using System.Windows;
using SHDocVw;
```

I realise I need to add the relevant components to my project but I'm not sure how to find the components that contain the classes. Perhaps there is a search somewhere?

Comment: Does the tutorial site not have the source code?

Comment: It has the source code listed, but doesn't mention the references that you need to add to the project. http://msmvps.com/blogs/vcsjones/archive/2010/05/23/writing-a-managed-internet-explorer-extension-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those examples are Namespaces that are located in assemblies that need to be reference. Luckily, adding those references are quite simple:

For System.Windows:

1. Right click your project.
2. Select "Add Reference..."
3. Select the ".NET" tab and find the System.Windows assembly.
4. Double click to add.

For SHDocVw:

1. Right click your project.
2. Select "Add Reference..."
3. Select the "Browse" tab.
4. Navigate to C:\Windows\System32
5. Find SHDocVw.dll
6. Double click to add.

Comment: Many thanks, it's good to have explicit instructions when you're new to a development language/environment. One problem I came up against was that System.Windows does not exist in the .NET tab. I have System.Windows.Presentation, ..ndows.Input.Manipulations, ..ndows.Forms.DataVisualization and ..ndows.Forms. I did manage to solve this by creating a WPF Application which seems to include the necessary assemblies out of the box. System.Windows is still not listed in the references though.

Comment: @opsb - System.Windows might actually be a Silverlight assembly. My fault. Don't forget, though, that namespaces can span several assemblies so by creating the WPF project it added other assembly references that contain classes that belong to the System.Windows namespace as well. It's easier to tell which assembly needs added if you know what class you need rather than the namespace you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid using the WPF as I don't want to include all the necessary components. It turns out that the necessary component is called WindowsBase and is also found on the .NET tab.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code you posted are not class but namespaces.

You can fidn what component to add by looking on the documentaion of the namespace.
Google after the namespace name and you will fidn the answer on MSDN.

Comment: Ah, I'm coming across from java, I hadn't realised you could use that syntax to import namespaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

its Microsoft Web Browser Control.

You should have it on your PC with name of

shdocvw32.dll

Reference it with your project.

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

Comment: I've found a few files that probably do a similar job. shodocvw.dll, Microsoft.ShDocVw.dll, AxInterop.ShDocVw.dll and Interop.ShDocVw.dll. How do I know which one to choose? Also, if I'm referring to a dll that's kept in some random part of the filesystem how can I share the project with other developers?